# Interpolation across different dataframes with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation

## Context of the Problem

I am running a discrete event simulation where at the end of each event I store the state of the system in a row of a dataframe. Each simulation run has a clock which determines which events are run and when, all the simulation have the same initial clock (0) and the same end clock (simulation end). but the number of rows for the dataframes may be different because the simulation has several stochastic components. The clock column is then converted to timestamp and use as index of the dataframe.

Whenever one does a simulation, it is good practice to run it many times and then average over all the replicates, doing so in this setup is a bit complicated because each simulation produced a dataframe which different indexes.

## Proposed Solution

So far this is the solution I found:

```
# Auxiliary functions
def get_union_index(dfs):
    index_union = dfs[0].index
    for df in dfs[1:]:
        index_union = index_union.union(df.index)
    return pd.Series(index_union).drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)

def interpolate(df, index, method='time'):
    aux = df.astype(float)
    aux = aux.reindex(index).fillna(method='ffill').fillna(method='bfill')
    return aux

# Simulation
dfs = []
replicates = 30
seeds = list(range(40, 40 + replicates))
dfs = [simulate(seed=seed, **parameters) for seed in seeds]

# Main Code
union_index = get_union_index(dfs)
dfs_interpolates = [interpolate(df, union_index) for df in dfs]
df_concat = pd.concat(dfs_interpolates)
by_row_index = df_concat.groupby(df_concat.index)

# Averaging
df_means = by_row_index.mean()
df_std = by_row_index.std()
```

### Explanation

First, it is necessary to combine all the indexes, then this combined index is used to re-index all the dataframes and the `nan` values are filled using interpolation.

### Questions

1. Is there a native pandas function that could simplify this?
2. (If not 1) Is there an alternative way to combine the datasets directly, since the majority of the index are disjoint, `union_index` has a length of approximately `len(df) * len(dfs)` which is actually huge.
3. In this case I am using `ffill` and then `bfill` but the solution should allow the more general `interpolate` method to support different and more complex approaches. The main issue is that since each row is an event (before interpolation), only a few columns (sometimes none) are changed in two consecutive rows, making it possible to have several consecutive rows with identical values in several columns and thus having a lot of redundant values, and even more after interpolation (especially for fill and bfill).

**EDIT**
Add data to reproduce and change question 3

`dfs` is a list of 3 DataFrames as follows:
[image]

Then `dfs_interpolates` is also a list of 3 DataFrames but this time the indexes are exactly the same, namely:

[image]

Finally the expected result should be a row-wise application of a function (mean, median, etc.) across the different dataframes in `dfs_interpolates`. For the case of the mean the result should be:

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide a sample dataframe and an expected output? Your question is well structured and you have explained your use case pretty well. But without data it is really hard to answer.

Comment: @above_c_level I've just added the necessary data (not sensitive). I showed the results of the simulation (input), the intermediate result, and the expected output. For simplicity reasons I rounded the values and only show 3 columns. Because in the simulation there is a "warming up" and each row represents normally a change in only one column, the first rows seem unnecessary duplicated, however, changes in non-showed columns were done.